# How can Promise.resolve().then execute later?

Tags: javascript, v8

Using native Javascript Promise:

```
Promise.resolve(1).then(it => console.log(it))
console.log(2)
```

This is logged:

```
2
1
```

Question: *how* is it possible for `2` to execute before `1`? JS being event-driven, what is the event that is executing the callback given to `then` when the original caller has already left that execution tree? Is the engine doing some kind of behind-the-scene magic here?

Comment: Your promise is asynchronous; if you want the promise executed before, you need to await it, or put the log(2) in the callback itself.

Comment: The Promise callback gets added to the micro-task queue, which then gets added to the callstack and executed only once your script has finished executing (ie: after console.log(2) has been logged).

Comment: @NickParsons Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for. Micro-tasks is the concept that I was missing out on. Care to post an Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript maintains something called a callstack. This is used to keep track of whereabouts in the script we are. When you call a function, it gets added to the callstack, and when the function returns/finishes, it gets removed/popped off the callstack. It is also helpful to think of your entire script also as being in its own "function", and so, when your script first begins its executing, we add "script" to the callstack:

```js
Stack:
- Script
```

When your Promise resolves, it executes its associated `.then()` method and adds the callback to something called the micro-task queue. This queue (along with the macro-task queue) is used so that JavaScript can manage asynchronous events. As a result, once you run:

```js
Promise.resolve(1).then(it => console.log(it))
```

the state of your queues/stacks looks like so (note, this is the state after Promise.resolve(1) and .then() have been added/popped off the callstack):

```js
Stack:
- Script

Micro task queue:
- it => console.log(it)
```

The callback in the micro-task queue will only execute once it gets added to the Stack. This happens through the use of the event-loop. The event-loop will pull tasks off the micro-task queue only when the callstack is empty. Currently, we are still running "script", so the callstack isn't empty yet.

Next, you encounter your `console.log(2)`, as this is a function call, it gets added to the call stack, and once it returns it gets popped off. This is the reason why you see `2` in the console appear first, as the Promise's `.then()` callback hasn't executed yet, as it's sitting in the micro-task queue waiting for the main script to finish. One the main script finishes, "script" gets popped off the stack:

```js
Stack:
- (empty) <----------------<
                           | --- gets moved to the stack by the event-loop
Micro task queue:          |
- it => console.log(it) ---^
```

the event loop then moves the task(s) from the micro-task queue now that the callstack is empty. Once the task is moved to the callstack, it executes, running the second `console.log(it)`. This is why you see `1` logged in the console after the `2`.